# Transform string format to list - it is not a json format string

Tags: java, string, arraylist

How to transform a string with this format into a list?

```
[[["Census_county_divisions","Populated_places_in_the_United_States","Populated_places_by_country","Geography_by_country","Geography_by_place","Geography","Main_topic_classifications"]],[["example","text","thanks"]],[["name","surname","age"]]]
```

From that string I would like to have 3 lists:

List 1:

```
"Census_county_divisions","Populated_places_in_the_United_States","Populated_places_by_country","Geography_by_country","Geography_by_place","Geography","Main_topic_classifications"
List 2:"example","text","thanks"
List 3:"name","surname","age"
```

I have tried different approachs do process this string, with split, with method StringUtils.substringBetween, with indexOf, with regex, with Json Parser.... I always get an error, is it an easier way out??

Comments: I don't see this string as a Json format, since the Json format would be "name":"John", If I'm wrong, please let me know how I could process it as a Json....

I have tried also with JsonParser and had the Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object:

`[[["Census_county_divisions","Popula`

Comment: There is one unnecessary nesting level. You could just have `[ [.. ], [.. ], [.. ] ]` and after that you have `List<List<String>>` type.

Comment: I recommend to use [JSONValidator](https://jsonlint.com/) to check if your test is relevant.

Comment: Whether you see it or not, this format is PERFECTLY VALID JSON, you may try any JSON validator to check this. The parsed string won't be a "JSON Object", but a **"JSON Array"**.
// Voted to close as a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I write this code:

1. remove the [[[,]]] strings
2. replace the ]],[[ for | character
3. split the string

   ```
   ///The String to convert
   String arg = "[[[\"Census_county_divisions\",.... 
   [[\"example\",\"text\",\"thanks\"]],[[\"name\",\"surname\",\"age\"]]]";

   System.out.println(arg);

   ////Replace 
   arg = arg.replace("[[[", "");
   arg = arg.replace("]],[[", "|");
   arg = arg.replace("]]]", "");

   System.out.println(arg);

   ////Split
   String[] array=arg.split("\\|");
   List<String> list =  Arrays.asList(array);

   ///Verify
   for(String s: list) {
       System.out.println(s);
   }
   ```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I only trimmed the start and end character set and then split it into 3 different strings which yielded the lists.

```
   str = new StringBuilder(str).replace(0, 4, "")
                               .reverse().replace(0, 4, "")
                               .reverse()
                               .toString();
   String[] arr1 = str.split("\"\\]\\],\\[\\[\"");
   List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(arr1[0]
                              .split("\",\""));
   List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(arr1[1]
                              .split("\",\""));
   List<String> list3 = Arrays.asList(arr1[2]
                              .split("\",\""));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use Regex to extract everything inside the "[[" "]]" and trimming the "[" and "]" at the start and the end of each group. After that, you could split the result and put it into a List.

Here a simple example:

```
    List<List<String>> lists = new ArrayList<>();
    String string = "[[[\"Census_cunty_divisions\",\"Populated_places_in_the_United_States\",\"Populated_places_by_country\",\"Geography_by_country\",\"Geography_by_place\",\"Geography\",\"Main_topic_classifications\"]],[[\"example\",\"text\",\"thanks\"]],[[\"name\",\"surname\",\"age\"]]]";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[(.*?)\\]\\]");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

    String proccesed;
    while (matcher.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
            proccesed = StringUtils.strip(matcher.group(i), "[");
            proccesed = StringUtils.strip(proccesed, "]");
            lists.add(Arrays.asList(proccesed.split(",")));
        }
    }

    int i = 0;
    for(List<String> stringList : lists){
        System.out.printf("List # %s \n", i);
        for(String elementOfList:stringList){
            System.out.printf("Element %s \n", elementOfList);
        }
        i++;
    }
```

Here you will have a dynamic list depending on the initial String.

I've used the [org.apache.commons](http://commons.apache.org/) commons-text library to strip the matches.

I hope it's useful.